# ParameterNotFoundException has been removed, but I still get the error?

Tags: symfony

I had this error while running phpunit on a symphony project

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "secret_parameter".
```

The parameter was in a .html.twig file. I attempted to suppress the error by removing the line with "secret_parameter".

The string "secret_parameter" is no longer in my project.

However, if I try to run phpunit, I still get the same error.

Why is that?

I have tried running this line to clear the cache but it has not helped:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

The full stacktrace of my error is:

```
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:84
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:200
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:171
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:161
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:161
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:161
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:45
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:39
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php:104
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:571
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:510
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:132
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:145
/home/jon/NetBeansProjects/spankthatmonkey/tests/HelloWorld/UserBundle/Entity/UserRepositoryTest.php:23
```

Comment: I suppose you try removing the var (or app) cache directory completely but it sure seems like you still have secret_parameter lurking around somewhere.  What you said about it being in a twig template is very confusing.  Make sure you have searched the entire project including the app and vendor directories.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

you are clearing the cache for the dev environement.

Phpunit use the test environnement.

You should do

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=test
```